# Why difference in Query response from Oracle using SQL Developer vs Python cx_Oracle library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

When I run the below query in Oracle SQL Developer, it works just fine and returns what I expect.

```
select to_timestamp(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH') - interval '1' hour, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual
```

But when I run it in Python using cx_Oracle, as below code, it fails with the below attached traceback.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import cx_Oracle
from datetime import date, datetime
import boto3
from io import StringIO
import dateutil.relativedelta
import traceback


dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('xyz', '1521', service_name='ABCD')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=testUser', password='user123', dsn=dsn_tns)
extraction_query = '''select to_timestamp(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH') - interval '1' hour, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual '''
```

Full traceback is as below:

```
Error in execution: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1595, in execute
cur.execute(*args)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01843: not a valid month



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):
File "oracle_query.py", line 30, in <module>
df_extracted_data =pd.read_sql(extraction_query,con=conn)
File "C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 410, in read_sql
chunksize=chunksize,
File "C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1645, in read_query
cursor = self.execute(*args)
File "C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1610, in execute
raise_with_traceback(ex)
File "C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 46, in raise_with_traceback
raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
File "C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1595, in execute
cur.execute(*args)
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select to_timestamp(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH') - interval '1' hour, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual ': ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Note: The connection is tested and it works fine for any other queries through python.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you used a wrong function; not `to_timestamp`, but `to_char` (if your goal is to format the result in that format mask):

```
SQL> select to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH') - interval '1' hour, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual
  2  /

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDA
-------------------
06-23-2021 21:00:00

SQL>
```

Why? Because the result - if you omit "that" function, is a date:

```
SQL> select TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH') - interval '1' hour from dual
  2  /

TRUNC(SY
--------
23.06.21
```

My database's settings are such that - by default - it is displayed as `dd.mm.yy`. If I change it:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

then the result looks as I wanted:

```
SQL> select TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH') - interval '1' hour from dual
  2  /

TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH')
-------------------
23.06.2021 21:00:00

SQL>
```

---

As you want to use that expression in a `where` clause: no problem, as long as you compare date-to-date, such as in the following example (sysdate is a function that returns `date` datatype value):

```
SQL> select 'x' result
  2  from dual
  3  where sysdate > TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH') - interval '1' hour;
           -------   ---------------------------------------
        this is DATE       and this is also DATE

RESULT
----------
x

SQL>
```

If you're comparing date-to-something-else, it is questionable whether it'll.

Comment: No, my target is do do timestamp comparison in the predicate (where) clause. The full query is working fine including the clause in Oracle SQL Developer, but isn't working in Python. Quite strange. Any clue?

Comment: It is "working" by *accident*. Your database's settings (or session's) are such that Oracle *knows* how to interpret value you provide to to_timestamp and returns the result. Meanwhile, I added some more info into the answer; have a look. I believe - based on your comment - that you don't need **any** function at all.

Comment: But the one you gave, when I put it in where clause to compare with a date time field, it gives the same error in python even though it runs fine in Oracle SQL Dev.

Comment: See yet another edit I posted, about the WHERE clause.

Comment: Oracle's `date` is essentially a datetime without fractional seconds. Most of the time you do bot need to concert it to timestamp explicitly, because oracle can compare dates and timestamps

Comment: Using Python, to_timestamp and to_char doesn't work, throws the same error even though it runs in Oracle SQL Developer, but to_date works, but it always sets the value of time to 00:00:00 and hence loses the essential time bit. Any help in Python? The above queries are all working in query editors and engines but not in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with different nls settings. Just compare the contents of nls_session_parameters and compare the data formats.

If you do implicit date format conversations the nls_date_format kicks in.

Never rely on those defaults, make sure that you control the conversions by specifying explicit patterns or setting the defaults that fit your app. It has not so much to do with python as with the other client tools.

Answer (score -1):

No given solutions worked, then I tried to tweak the functions and used nested functions and finally the following worked in Python successfully:

```
to_date(to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH') - interval '1' hour, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

All the other solutions gave the same error as below in Python:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

Whoever faces this problem, please go ahead and use the above solution, it will work in predicate clause.

Comment: `to_date` or `to_timestamp` accepts character input, but `trunc(sysdate, 'HH')` is a date. So `trunc(sysdate, 'HH') - interval '1' hour` is still a date. You do not need to convert it to char and back

Comment: Can you please try this in Python? You'd essentially get an error when running the query, so double explicit casting solved it for us. But I know what you say totally makes sense.

Comment: I suggest you go back over the large answer. Whenever you use to_char or to_date without an explicit date format or somehow treat a date/string as a string/date, Oracle will use your sessions NLS settings. In SQL Developer, these accidentally defaulted nicely for you, in Python they did not. Your expression here can be simplified to  `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH') - interval '1' hour` without concerning ourselves with to_date or to_char because `SYSDATE` is a date, `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH')` is a date, `date type - interval type` is a date, no conversion necessary.